# ERROR '_ImageSchema' object has no attribute 'readImages'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Trying to load image from folder in pyspark

```
from pyspark.ml.image import ImageSchema
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

zero_df = ImageSchema.readImages('../Transfer-Learning- 
PySpark/images/o').withColumn("label",lit(0))
```

throws error

```
     AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-9-29c9b120f9c2> in <module>
                   2 from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
                    3 
     ----> 4 zero_df = ImageSchema.readImages('../Transfer-Learning- 
     PySpark/images/o').withColumn("label",lit(0))

     AttributeError: '_ImageSchema' object has no attribute 'readImages'
```

Python 3.8
Spark v3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spark 2.4, images can be loaded directly with a [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) using the format `image`:

```scala
zero_df = spark.read.format("image").load(<path to files>)
```

More details can be found [here](https://databricks.com/de/blog/2018/12/10/introducing-built-in-image-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html).

The usage of `ImageSchema.readImages` as been [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/96f51378b598501cc5dc5791f794c8586a48b355/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/image/ImageSchema.scala#L201) since then and the method has been removed in Spark 3.0.0